# Django Filtering - Field 'testcaseidstring' expected a number but got 'tc123'

Tags: python, django

I am trying to apply a filter on a Django model based on a column name

That column is a Foreign Key

**Code** -

Inside **models.py** -

```
class History(models.Model):
    testcaseidstring = models.ForeignKey('Testcaseidstructure', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='testCaseIdString')
```

Inside **views.py** -

```
sessid_qs=History.objects.using("otherdb").filter(testcaseidstring="tc123")
```

This gives me the following ERROR -
***Field 'testcaseidstring' expected a number but got 'tc123'***

How am I supposed to filter on this column?

**Testcaseidstructure module**:

```
class Testcaseidstructure(models.Model):
    testcaseidstring = models.TextField(db_column='testCaseIdString')
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'testCaseIdStructure'
```

Any help would be highly appreciable

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ForeignKey *is* a number, unless you defined a custom primary key in your model.  It's the primary key of the Testcaseidstructure model, so despite the fact that you call it testcaseidstring, it is probably not a string, so rename it `testcase`.  If you want to filter by the string, then you can do something like this:

```py
class History(models.Model):
    testcase = models.ForeignKey('Testcaseidstructure', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='testCaseIdString')
```

Then

```py
sessid_qs=History.objects.using("otherdb").filter(testcase__testcaseidstring="tc123")
```

As suggested by weAreStarDust.  Make sure there are two underscores here, `testcase__testcaseidstring='tc123'`

Answer (score 1):

I gues if you want filter by column name you should use `testcaseidstring__name` in filter, or whatever your name field called in `Testcaseidstructure` model.

Comment: Using ```testcaseidstring__name``` .i.e. ```testcaseidstring__testcaseidstring``` causes this error 
```Unsupported lookup 'testcaseidstring' for AutoField or join on the field not permitted.```
I have added that module in the question now..

Comment: Yes I tried with that

```Unsupported lookup 'testcaseidstring' for AutoField or join on the field not permitted.```

This is what is shows.

This is what I tried


```sessid_qs=History.objects.using("otherdb").filter(testcaseidstring__testcaseidstring="tc123")```

Comment: Like this right?
```sessid_qs=History.objects.using("otherdb").filter(testcaseidstring__testcaseidstring="tc123")```

Comment: Yes, right. can you rename foriengkey value or field in model with different names? :) It's not good if they are equal.

Comment: "Inside models.py -" part in your question is `History` model part?

Comment: yes that is a part of History

Comment: Even this method ```sessid_qs=History.objects.using("otherdb").filter(testcaseidstring__testcaseidstring="tc123")``` is giving the same error actually

Comment: Any idea how this can be solved?